# How to create struct of every word in .txt file in C?

Tags: c, file, struct, io

if given a short .txt file that contained the following content, how would you go about creating a struct for every word in a specific line in the file and determining if it had an * before it

Sample File:

```
a *b c 
*d e f
```

I have created this structs:

```
typedef struct Unit
{
    bool hasStar;
    char variable[1];
} unit;
```

So I would want to create a struct for a, *b, and c for example. I'm not sure how to do this, so any help on how best to approach this would be amazing

Comment: How should these structs be stored?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda im making a struct variable for every letter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to change `char variable[1]` to `char varibale[3]` at least for storing the string "*a" for example.

You can get line by line from the file using `fgets` then using `strtok` to separate the line by space character.

```
FILE *fp = fopen("intput.txt", "r");
if(!fp)
  // handle error.
char line[256];
while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) {
    // using strtok to split each line
}
```

For spliting the line using `strtok` and verify the star symbol `*` at the begin of word:

```
char * token = strtok(line, " ");
while (token != NULL) {
    strcpy(units[i].variable, token);
    if (token[0] == '*')
       units[i].hasStar = true;
    else
        units[i].hasStar = false;
    strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
}
```

Before `while` loop of `fgets`, you have to declare the size of `units` and initialize `i` first, for example the code below, i initialize the size of array `units` that is eaqual to 100:

```
unit units[100];
int i = 0;
```

Comment: ok this kinda makes sense. just for clarification on the first part of what you said, its variable[1] because i am making a struct variable for every letter on the line containing the bool and what the letter is

Comment: if you want to store char value, you do not need to use array . So, use `char value` is enough. Y