# Is it possible to take a token from a file and create a struct with it using malloc in C?

Tags: c, struct, malloc, token, dynamic-memory-allocation

I need to use both `malloc` and `realloc` and am confused how to do it.

Assuming that the input file looks something like this:

```
a *b c
a
*a b *c
```

and I have structs set up as so:

```
typedef struct Unit {
    bool hasAstericks;
    char letter;
} unit;

typedef struct Line {
    struct unit clause[4]
} line;
```

Is it possible to create a struct of type `unit` from each letter add them to an array in struct `Line` based off of the line they are on? I've tried using loops but couldn't create structs on the fly with them.

This is what I have tried:

```
int c;
filename = argv[1];
char *filename;
FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");  
filename = (char *)malloc(size);

do {
    c = fgetc(fp);
    inputFile = (char *)realloc(inputFile, size + 1);
    inputFile[n] = c;
    n++;
    size++;
} while (c != EOF);
```

Comment: show what you tried

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create struct of every word in .txt file in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61353365/how-to-create-struct-of-every-word-in-txt-file-in-c)

Comment: @Hitokiri sorta, but i was looking to use malloc and realloc

Comment: @pm100 edited now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `do`/ `while` loop attempts to read the file into a array of `char` which you reallocate for each additional byte read from he file.

Yet you should test for end-of-file **before** storing the byte into the array.

Also it might be best to set a null terminator at the end of the array when you are done, so the array should have `size + 1` bytes.

Here you code modified and encapsulated in a function to read the file:

```
char *read_file(const char *filename) {
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");  
    if (fp == NULL)
        return NULL;
    size_t size = 0;
    char *p = malloc(size + 1);
    if (p != NULL) {
        int c;
        while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {   
            char *newp = realloc(p, size + 2);
            if (newp == NULL) {
                free(p);
                p = NULL;
                break;
            }
            p = newp;
            p[size] = c;
            size++;
        }
        if (p) {
            p[size] = '\0';  set a null terminator: make p a C string.
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return p;
}
```